# Зачем и как разделять код в PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Наверное вопрос типичный, но типичные ответы я прочитал.

Допустим я делаю небольшое приложение на php. Не используя никаких сторонних библиотек.

Я новичек в PHP. 'Только что' начал его использовать.

Весь html выводится с помощью PHP.

Фронт и бэк перемешаны в файлах. Т.е. всякие вызовы к базе и выводы html находятся в одном месте. 
Сейчас мне это никак не мешает. Но я прочитал что PHP желательно разделять на части - одна чтобы отвечала за фронт, а другая за соединения с базой и всю остальную логику.

Зачем так делать? Повышается масштабируемость и скорость обслуживания кода?

Как это лучше сделать?

Вот допустим у меня в файле запускается цикл, в котором выводится html и туда подставляются данные из базы, которые тоже получены строками выше.

Реквайрить эти данные из отдельного файла? И в самом файле будет происходить запрос к базе и запись этих данных в переменные? Потом просто расставить переменные?

Спасибо.

Comment: зачем? потому что бизнес-логика это одно, а представление это другое. Есть две задачи - обработать запрос и подготовить данные и второе - представить эти данные. Любую задачу решать проще если ее разделить на части. PHP код вперемешку с html становится нечитаемым, ошибки логики мешаются с ошибками вывода. Это как пойти в столовую вылить чай в суп и потом думать, чай горький или суп сладкий, и понимать, что в тарелке какая-то херня.
проще всего отделить логику от представления используя шаблоны а-ля Smarty или еще какие-нибудь.

Comment: но ведь полностью убрать хтмл теги из php кода никак нельзя.

Comment: Главный принцип при программировании на любом языке это "управление сложностью" раскладывая код по разным файлам, каталогам вы управляете сложностью конечно только в том случае когда имя файла соответствует его содержимому. Советую прочитать книги Роберт Мартин - Чистый код. или Макконел - Совершенный код. Обе книги рассказывают о хороших практиках программирования и показывают примеры плохого и хорошего кода.

Answer (score 2):

Вам станет намного более понятным ответ если программирование Вы начнёте с карандаша. Почиркайте по бумаге и код сам разбежится по различным квадратикам.

Разбивка кода очень удобна при многопользовательской разработке. Не очень удобно получить при очередном pull получить сотни правок на один файл.

Ну а если маленький наколенный проектик, то можно и одним файлом. Но это прививает вредную привычку и не замечаешь как уже и большое пишешь монолитным файлом. А потом отучаться плохо.

Иное дело что не нужно фанатизма. Не стоит каждую строку выделять в файл.

То что Вы привели как пример... Зависит от нюансов. Насколько сложен каждый блок, насколько сильно планируется его развивать, один разработчик, или эту часть отдают другому разработчику. А может это вообще открытая среди проприетарного...

Answer (score 2):

Никогда не мешайте логику с представлением. 
А теперь просто задайте себе ряд вопросов и вы сами же найдёте на многие из них ответы:

- А что если в ряде запросов нам нужно будет обращаться к другой СУБД? Удобно ли будет поддерживать всё это в текущем виде?
- Что если нам нужно будет изменить целый блок? Удобно будет искать его среди логики и править?
- Что если дизайном будет заниматься другой человек? Каково ему будет копаться в этих файлах, не лучше ли вынести представление отдельно, используя Smarty, Twig и прочие шаблонизаторы?
- и т.д. и т.п.

Задавая себе вопросы, вы решите множество проблем на начальной стадии, но опыт и практику конечно же тоже никто ещё не отменял.